# ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython

Tags: android, ssl, kivy, cython, buildozer

OS - Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS;  python3;   kivy 1.11.1;
cython - 0.29.9 (as recommended for kivy 1.11.1, but also tried the latest version at today's date)

When I executed buildozer -v android debug, many errors came but were sorted out with the blessings of Google search. But this took me almost 3 days and I'm still stuck. I've captured screenshots for detailed description but I guess the problem is with cython or tls/ssl module.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, this fixed it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

(I also deleted the .buildozer folder before running buildozer again.)

(see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61712462/13350398)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not installing `libssl-dev` while installing dependences for buildozer.

Run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
buildozer android clean
```

And then do

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

This should do the trick.

For detailed answer refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68452097/2504434).