# Why am I getting error saying "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython"

Tags: ubuntu, kivy, virtualbox, cython, buildozer

**What am I trying to achieve?**

I am trying to finish tuotorial on making android app with kivy with buildozer running in Ubuntu VirtualBox inside windows 10 (isntructions from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EupAeyL8zAo) and run the app on my mobile device.

**Where am I having problems?**

For five times I've tried this I have had this error after running command `buildozer android debug deploy run` (from inside the project's folder): [image]

**What have I tried to fix this?**

- I installed cython to both my windows 10 (with `pip install Cython` and `pip3 install Cython`) and Ubunu inside VirtualBox. In every instance I got `Requirement already satisfied...`.
- I started new VirtualBox enviroment after installing Cython to windows 10.
- I tried following these instructons/commands: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68452164/14694631

**PS**

In many posts I have seen people asking for full logs. Still after reading many issues on this subject I am still clueless on what the full log actually means. If error message provided is not the right part I can try to get the full log also if I can. Also I am new to Kivy, buildozer and VirtualBox and I've never used ubuntu for dev stuff before.

Comment: Do you have openssl installed in your Ubuntu?

Comment: @JohnAnderson, Yes. I checked with command ``openssl version`` and got ``OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020`` in ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but try `pip install pyopenssl`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Sadly still the same error.

Comment: Try `apt install libssl-dev && buildozer android clean` on ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

I've seen a similar error before and seems that when installing python, some essential modules, `ssl`, weren't and are missing.

#### The Problem

`pip` seems to fail when trying to download *Cython* during the build, as it needs the `ssl` module in python which isn't available

#### The Solution

re-installing Python3 as it seems an essential library (`ssl`) wasn't installed.

You could use [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3/44758621#44758621) for help in fixing the ssl error in pip, and you should then retry the build

To re-install python, it says to:

1. Run `sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev` for dependancies
2. Download and unzip "Python-3.x.x.tar.xz" (your choice of version) from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/ into your home directory.
3. Open terminal in that directory and run: `./configure`
4. Build and install: `make && sudo make install`

After re-installing python, check if pip works by running `pip install --upgrade pip`

If you need more clarifications, just comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found fix in the comments of the tutorial.

1. `sudo apt install libssl-dev`
2. `rm -rf .buildozer`
3. Deploy app again

Here is the whole comment by tutorial maker Erik Sanberg:

> Try `sudo apt install libssl-dev` and then `rm -rf .buildozer` in the directory that has your buildozer.spec file. Then you can try deploying it again. It's a bug recently introduced that will be patched up soon I believe.

Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EupAeyL8zAo

Comment: link to the tutorial you got this from

Comment: The same tutorial that question was referencing. But for clarity I editet it into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same prob when I was trying to install mobsf. Here is how I managed to fix it:

First, locate `oscrypto/version.py` and check what's the value of `__version__`.

Then, just hardcode it inside `oscrypto/_openssl/_libcrypto_cffi.py`,
find where the variable called `version_string` is being set, comment that link and just set `version_string = "THE VALUE YOU FOUND INSIDE version.py"`

Please note that this may not be the best solution, but it worked for me after trying all the above answers.