# Issue with converting kivy app to apk (Problem confirming SSL certificate)

Tags: python, android, kivy, apk

Hi I am trying to convert my Kivy app that I recently just built to an android APK file however I come across the error below can someone please explain what the issue is and help me resolve it been trying for hours looking through multiple vids cant seem to fix it. I am unsure if it is to do with Cython as I have already installed cython using pip and it still gives me this error.

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/cython/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/cython/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping


    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Cython (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Cython
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

STDERR:

# Command failed: /usr/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=SmartFitApp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,kivymd,requests,certifi --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/muhammed/SmartFitApp/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/muhammed-VirtualBox:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1488,unix/muhammed-VirtualBox:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1488'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_GB:en'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1436'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     PWD = '/home/muhammed/SmartFitApp'
#     LOGNAME = 'muhammed'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     GPG_AGENT_INFO = '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/gdm/Xauthority'
#     GJS_DEBUG_TOPICS = 'JS ERROR;JS LOG'
#     WINDOWPATH = '2'
#     HOME = '/home/muhammed'
#     USERNAME = 'muhammed'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LANG = 'en_GB.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6003'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/ed9d6f50_8c93_495d_aa22_80be47489274'
#     INVOCATION_ID = '9175df48578f40e294a885f1c6532c30'
#     MANAGERPID = '1224'
#     GJS_DEBUG_OUTPUT = 'stderr'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'muhammed'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.88'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     JOURNAL_STREAM = '8:32637'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = '/home/muhammed/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/muhammed/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/muhammed'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/muhammed/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/muhammed/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/muhammed/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This particular part in your stack trace is the error (first line)

```
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate
```

This occurs when the buildozer dependency `libssl-dev` is missed out.

Run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
buildozer android clean
```

And then do

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
```

This should do the trick.

For detailed answer refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68452097/2504434).